# Transferring local PHP/HTML site and database to wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I've created a project that is almost all PHP/HTML, except for 5 lines of ajax/javascript in one page. It's been approved but it needs to be part of a wordpress site on a subdomain. I'm familiar with importing a MySQL database and setting up a user for that, and I'm also familiar with putting the db credentials in the wp-config.php file for the main site database.

I have a plugin that allows for save insertion of PHP into pages/posts, but I really don't know the best way to do this. I have 6 or 7 pages of php and one database with 7 tables.

Is there anyone familiar with the best way to go about this? Everything works perfectly on my local server, I just need it to work correctly via wordpress.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the best solution to this by duplicating my theme page template and creating a template for each PHP file.